# Best reason of leaving job after 1 month?

Tags: job-change

What is the best reason to give my boss on why I'm leaving after 1 month? I don't want to burn that bridge if possible, and come back later on in the future.

Comment: The truth is often the best reason.

Comment: Just tell them the truth. If it is reasonable and your boss is understandable you might leave the company without burning the bridges.

Comment: Why are you leaving after one month?

Answer (score 6):

The truth (formulated nicely).

Lying is the best way to burn bridges permanently.